# Audio processing Conv1D keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am learning Keras using audio classification, Actually, I am implementing the code with modification from https://github.com/deepsound-project/genre-recognition/blob/master/train_model.py using Keras.

The shape of the dataset is

```
X_train shape = (800, 32, 1)
y_train shape = (800, 10)
X_test shape = (200, 32, 1)
y_test shape = (200, 10)
```

The model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(32,1),     activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu", ))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001),
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
)
model.summary()

red_lr= ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',patience=2,verbose=2,factor=0.5,min_delta=0.01)
check=ModelCheckpoint(filepath=r'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/gen/cnn.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only = True)

History = model.fit(X_train,
                y_train,
                epochs=100,
                #batch_size=512,
                validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
                verbose = 2,
                callbacks=[check, red_lr],
                shuffle=True )
```

[The accuracy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmyCp.png)

[Loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trlXc.png)

I do not understand, Why the val_acc is in the range of 70%. I tried to modify the model architecture including optimizer, but no improvement.

And, Is it good to have a lot of difference between loss and val_loss.

how to improve the accuracy above 80... any help...

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you increase patience to 20 and remove `red_lr`?

Comment: I checked, it returns val_acc as 52%...

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I use concatenate function from Keras to concatenate all convolution layers and, it gives the best performance.